# Fastest way to calculate modulus in a large list of numbers

Tags: c++, modulus

I am trying to write a c++ program to find all numbers with a certain range say (1 till 3 billion) that are perfectly divisible by a number say N. I was wondering if I could get pointers to do this as efficiently as possible.

Very Basic:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3 BIllion; i++)
{
    if (i % N == 0) print (i);
}
```

I am sure there will be better solutions, as this will take a long time. Would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Not sure how serious you are about "efficiently as possible" or how practical this question really is. May be better places to ask, and probably on an Assembly forum.  Your first hotpot is probably your printing code. (I do like Oli's answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than testing all numbers in turn, why not just explicitly generate the multiples?

```
#include <cstdint>

uint32_t i = 0;
while (i < 3000000000)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
    i += N;
}
```

Comment: `i` will probably need to be an unsigned int, as 3 billion is beyond the range of 31 bits.

Comment: Thank you, I was doing something similar. I guess I was over complicating the situation by thinking that I should do some bit manipulation magic to optimise the mod, but I guess that is not necessary as the compiler would optimise better than I would anyway.